# Pagina empresas por categoria Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando paginar las empresas por categorias, con la idea que me quede una estructura de vista parecida a esta:

```
----------------------------
Categoria: Panaderia
----------------------------
Empresa: Panaderia X
Empresa: Panaderia Y
Empresa: Panaderia Z

Pagina 1,2,3

----------------------------
Categoria: Ferreteria
----------------------------
Empresa: Ferreteria X
Empresa: Ferreteria Y
Empresa: Ferreteria Z

Pagina 1,2,3

----------------------------
Categoria: Hoteles
----------------------------
Empresa: Hoteles X
Empresa: Hoteles Y
Empresa: Hoteles Z

Pagina 1,2,3
```

Esto lo logro conseguir sin ningun problema ordenandolos por group_by de la siguiente manera:

**enterprises_controller.rb**

```
@enterprises = Enterprise.all.group_by { |e| e.enterprise_tag }
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @enterprises.each do |enterprise_tag, enterprises| %>
   <%= enterprise_tag %>
   <% enterprises.each do |enterprise| %>
      <%= enterprise.name %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @enterprises, :container => false %>
```

El problema viene cuando intento agregar el paginador de esta forma:

```
@enterprises = Enterprise.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6).group_by { |e| e.enterprise_tag }
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Hash:0x007f7450797d10>
Extracted source (around line #73):

73 <%= will_paginate @enterprises, :container => false %>
```

He intentado varias formas pero no logro dar con el resultado, ¿alguien podria darme una sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que group_by no te está devolviendo una relación de *ActiveRecords* sino un hash. Hasta donde vi en la documentación de la gema *will_paginate* no acepta hashes. Creo que *Keminari* es un poco más flexible pero no le he usado.

Una solución posible es agrupar los resultados en las vistas. Para ello nos tenemos que asegurar de ordenar los resultados por la columna con la que queremos agrupar. En tu caso *enterprise_tag*

```
#enterprises_controller.rb
def index
  # Devuelve una relación de ActiveRecord con la que puede trabajar will_paginate
  @enterprises = Enterprise.order(enterprise_tag: :asc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
end

#index.html.erb
...
<% enterprise_tag = nil %>
<% @enterprises.each do |enterprise| %>
  <% unless enterprise_tag == enterprise.enterprise_tag
    <h3><%= enterprise.enterprise_tag %></h3>
    <% enterprise_tag = enterprise.enterprise_tag %>
  <% end %>
  <h4><%= enterprise.name %></h4>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @enterprises %>
```

Como ves en la vista creamos y utilizamos una variable *enterprise_tag* para saber si es la primera entrada con ese tag y en ese caso ponerlo como título.

**Edición: *enterprise_tag* es una tabla relacionada**

En este caso es mucho más fácil. No listamos las empresas sino las categorías y dentro de cada una hacemos un loop con las empresas de esa categoría.

```
#app/models/enterprise.rb
class Enterprise < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :enterprise_tag
  ...
end

#app/models/enterprise_tag.rb
class EnterpriseTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :enterprises
  ...
end

#app/controllers/enterprises_controller.rb
def index
  # Devuelve una relación de ActiveRecord con la que puede trabajar will_paginate
  @categorias = EnterpriseTag.includes(:enterprises).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
end

#index.html.erb
...
<% @categorias.each do |categoria| %>
  <h3><%= categoria.nombre %></h3>
  <% categoria.enterprises.each do |enterprise| %>
    <h4><%= enterprise.nombre %></h4>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @categorias %>
```

**Notas:**

- No se como se llama la columna con el nombre en ninguno de los dos modelos así que puse *nombre*. Reemplazar con lo que corresponda.
- Incluyo el *.includes(:enterprises) para evitar una nueva llamada a la base de datos para cada categoría (N+1).

Comment: Va genialisimo Lastimoso! Oye ¿de que otra forma un tanto mas limpia se podria refactorizar ese codigo? Con tu codigo me va fenomenal todo, intente refactorizar de cierta forma ese codigo, condiciono que en caso de no tener la categoria alguna empresa asociada, oculte la categoria, pero lo malo es que me deja el paginador vacio, y tengo q continuar a la siguiente pagina donde si existen categorias con empresas asociadas, no se si me doy a entender

Este es la idea que tengo:
https://gist.github.com/hernandezalek/2ebeddd23a434595dd61dc91907fc30a

Comment: Me alegro que sirva! Para poder ayudarte con esto por favor explícame mejor a que te referís. Estamos hablando de una sola tabla (Enterprises) con una columna llamada Enterprise_tag, ¿no? En ese caso como podría haber una categoría sin empresas. Si por el contrario, Tag es una tabla asociada a Enterprises la solución es todavía más sencilla. O ¿queres decir que una empresa puede tener enterprice_tag vacía y que esto te rompe la paginación? Avísame y edito la respuesta!

Comment: Pude ver el archivo de Github pero no podría funcionar. En tu controlador estás armando una colección de Empresas, pero tu código de la vista asume que estás armando una colección de Categorías (enterprise_tags). Por eso te preguntaba si enterprise_tag es una asociación de enterprise (una tabla propia) o una columna (string) de la tabla enterprise. Con esa aclaración podré ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Hola Lastimoso! Si asi es, es una tabla asociada llamada "enterprise_tag", donde tiene muchas empresas "enterprises" y cada empresa pertenece a una categoria de "enterprise_tag"

Comment: Agregada la solución para ese caso Hector. Suerte con esto y espero que sirva.

Comment: Va perfecto!! Te agradezco muchisimo @lastimoso! Me has sacado del atolladero! =D

Comment: Me alegro que sirva!